# Flutter AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad , {errorCode: 2} previously works fine but now shows error

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies

I run recent days it works totally fine without any issues but now without any changes in code it throws AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad , {errorCode: 2}, I have good internet connection and also I tried different packages for admob but showing same error and I am using test ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched off the device and turn on and now it works fine, I don't know what happend!